# Equivalence of the category of punctured compact Riemann surfaces and smooth algebraic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider the category whose objects are of the form
$X\backslash E$ where $X$ is a compact Riemann surface and $E\subset X$ is a finite subset, and whose morphisms are holomorphic maps $X\backslash E\rightarrow Y\backslash E'$ that extend to holomorphic maps $X\rightarrow Y$. I'm trying to show that this category is equivalent to the category of smooth algebraic curves and algebraic maps. In this context I'm taking an algebraic map $f:A\rightarrow A'$ between two algebraic curves to be a map such that $f$
can be expressed locally as the restriction of a polynomial function in affine charts around each point of $A$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_algebraic_varieties). My question is how to show that an algebraic map between algebraic curves is a holomorphic map that extends to a holomorphic map between the compactifications of the source and target?

Comment: This is a repost of your [previously deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053487/equivalence-of-the-category-of-punctured-compact-riemann-surfaces-and-smooth-alg). That's not acceptable.

Comment: Why not? I'm new here so I don't understand. My question was heavily edited and I thought maybe that was the reason no one answered, so I decided to repost the more detailed version of the question.

Comment: Deleting and reposting your question to try and drum up new interest is contrary to expectations here: see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/should-i-delete-and-repost-my-question-to-regenerate-interest). Besides, you already had someone who promised an answer at your deleted question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't realise it was a bad thing to do this if the question had been significantly edited. (Also the person who promised an answer didn't actually respond, which confused me)